# NW: extension turtle-in-radius

Tags: netlogo

I have created a graph to mirror that of a road network (i.e. G = (V, E)).  This comprises a number of junction, terminus and intermediate nodes (V).  Terminus nodes have 1 link (E), intermediate nodes 2 and junction nodes more than 2.

What I am trying to do is identify the separate parts of the graph that form connections between either terminus-junction or junction-junction nodes.  I was thinking of using nw:turtles-in-radius to do this, but this requires a fixed search range to be specified.  I was wondering does anyone

- have an idea how to identify how far other junction/terminus node are
  away from the searching node, such that i can specify it in the turtles-in-radius function?
- or have an idea for a better way of identifying the network sections?

Once I have identified these sections I will then store the turtles located along them in a list for later operations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `nw:turtles-in-radius` will help you much, here. It's not a simple problem. I found a fairly convoluted way of doing it. Perhaps someone else will come up with something simpler.

The setup is just there for testing:

```
extensions [ nw ]
to setup
  clear-all
  ; generate a simple network for testing
  nw:generate-ring turtles links 5
  ask n-of 2 turtles [
    hatch 1 [
      create-link-with myself
      hatch 1 [ create-link-with myself ]
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [ set label who ]
  repeat 1000 [ layout-spring turtles links 0.2 5 1 ]
end
```

The rest is made from a bunch of reporters that compose in a fairly functional way:

```
to go
  let nodes [ self ] of turtles with [ not is-intermediate? ]
  let sections unique-sections reduce sentence map my-sections nodes
  foreach sections print
end

to-report my-sections [ node ]
  report map [ section-from node ? ] [ sort link-neighbors ] of node
end

to-report section-from [ n1 n2 ]
  report ifelse-value [ is-intermediate? ] of n2 [
    fput n1 section-from n2 
      [ one-of link-neighbors with [ self != n1 ] ] of n2
  ] [
    list n1 n2
  ]
end

to-report is-intermediate?
  report count my-links = 2
end

to-report unique-sections [ all-sections ]
  let sections []
  foreach all-sections [
    if not member? reverse ? sections [
      set sections lput ? sections
    ]
  ]
  report sections
end
```

You can drop the call to `unique-sections` if you don't need them to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to Nicolas.

In the end, after looking at graph theory a bit more, I decided to use the weak component cluster route.  To identify clusters i set the context as only nodes with two connections. So removing junctions and terminus nodes. I then used nw:weak-component-clusters.  This gave me a list of turtles present in each component.  I then iterated over this list and gave each turtle-set a unique identifier. I now have a list of nodes which knows who else it links with.